# FacetWP, query from today's date

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

i'm looking for a way to query posts with a date from today (current day).

My query looks like that :

```js
<?php
return [
  "post_type" => [
    "event"
  ],
  "post_status" => [
    "publish"
  ],
  "meta_query" => [
    "0" => [
      "key" => "date",
      "compare" => ">",
      "type" => "DECIMAL(16,4)",
      "value" => "XXXXX"
    ],
    "sort_0" => [
      "key" => "date",
      "type" => "CHAR"
    ]
  ],
  "orderby" => [
    "sort_0" => "ASC"
  ],
  "posts_per_page" => "4"
];
```

I don't know what to set on TYPE and VALUE.
Is this possible to help me please?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, you're looking just to query any event that is today and in the future? If so, type can be `DATETIME` and the value can be what you return using php `DateTime`

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found out how to do it :)

Here is the snippet I should have used :

```js
<?php
return [
  "post_type" => [
    "event"
  ],
  "post_status" => [
    "publish"
  ],
  "meta_query" => [
    "sort_0" => [
      "key" => "date",
      "compare" => ">",
      "type" => "DATE",
      "value" => date("Y-m-d"),
    ]
  ],
  "orderby" => [
    "sort_0" => "ASC"
  ],
  "posts_per_page" => "4"
];
```